# how does this protect against csrf attacks?

Tags: php, security, cors, csrf

I'm working on making my opencart project and used [This Article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-api-in-opencart--cms-26018)  to write custom apis.

It uses this block of code to do a security check against csrf attacks:

```
    if (isset($this->request->server['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
      $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $this->request->server['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
      $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
      $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
      $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    }
```

My question is how is that going to protect against csrf attacks according to the article? It seems it just sets Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to whatever domain the request is coming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not protect against CSRF attacks at all, because you are allowing all origins! It is the same writing as

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

You should create a list of acceptations like below, which ensures only those in the list are granted for CORS.

> `Scheme`, `Domain` and `Port` are the important information to compare against. Port can be omitted, when defaults are to be used like http=80 and https=443.

```php
if(in_array($this->request->server['HTTP_ORIGIN'], [
    'http://xxx-domain.org',
    'https://example.org',
    'http://localhost:8888',
])) {
    $this->response->addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$this->request->server['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
}
```